# JavaScript array.forEach

Tags: javascript

I was searching for a simple click event script without the use of jQuery, and found some usefull code. With this I created my own variant of this code, which works, but there is one thing I don't get

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("a"), function (el) {
    el.addEventListener("click", function (ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        this.style.backgroundColor = "grey";
    })
});
```

This code grabs all `<a>`-elements on the webpage and adds a click event which changes the background colour to gray.

However, I don't get why `forEach.call()` executes while the array `[]` is empty.

**Could someone explain how this works?**

Comment: Just a couple notes on performance...querySelectorAll() returns a live node list, so it reruns the query every time you access it. You'd be better off converting it to an array first before using forEach. Also, if you want to style links on click, you could always just use a:active in CSS.

Comment: The styling of links was done so I could run it in the web console on any page.

Comment: @Broxzier Fair enough :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`function.call()` runs a function with a different `this`.

Your code creates an empty array to get at the `forEach` method (it would be better to write `Array.prototype.forEach`, then calls `call()` to call it on the array-like NodeList.

Answer (score 2):

Although `[]` is an array, we're using the prototype function `forEach` exposed on this type.

This is a shorthand for using `Array.prototype.forEach.call();`

Comment: That explains a lot, thanks.